# How to access file in src/main/resources EXTERNALLY

Tags: java, file

I am able to read a file in src/main/resources using

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test-file.xml");
```

In my case I can access this but I have no way to edit it.
However, this file needs to be editable when the file is deployed using a war file.

I need to:
Whenever the test-file is updated externally, changes can also be seen on the deployed website.
Do you have a way to do this?
I am using springboot btw.

Comment: A war file is just a zip archive, so you can use the regular zip classes to do whatever you want with its contents. Cannot imagine a requirement where your described approach would be the preferred solution though.

Comment: Resources are read-only.  Don’t try to write to them.  Some systems will not even let you write to them.  And even if you can, your program may not see the changes.  The correct way to do this is to treat your resource as a read-only *default data set,* and store the modified version in an external file or in a database.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not not storing it in src/main/resources, I just put the file beside the war file, and access it externally instead.

Comment: If it’s not inside your application, you cannot use getResource or getResourceAsStream to read it.  There is no reliable way to find that location.  External configuration belongs in a known location, like `System.getProperty("user.home")` or a descendant directory of it.

Comment: sorry, I constructed my sentence wrong. I changed the location of my file after reading your answer (VGR's and Robby's). Since you both said it is read-only, I put it outside instead. And access it via a property source file. Thanks guys!